# Dependent JAR: cannot find properties file

Tags: spring, properties

I have a library using Spring and loading its own properties file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:connectors.properties")
```

When using this JAR as a Maven dependency, and putting that class under scanning, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:connectors.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

What is the proper way in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Decompile the jar and share the image containing the above file in it.

Comment: the file "connectors.properties" is not in it, guess that's the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually as pointed out by @Barath, the file had not been packaged in the dependent JAR, as it was present in src/test/resources and not src/main/resources